# Does TortoiseSVN have application logs?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I'm trying to get TortoiseSVN to keep application logs to understand what's not working when I'm trying to update or checkout a repository.

I found it very hard to Google this given the use of the word 'log' in the world of SVN itself.

So: how can I ask TortoiseSVN to give me the most verbose log possible of its actions and ensuing errors?

Comment: You'd better ask about particular errors that you get.

Comment: I guess so.. I really wish TortoiseSVN had a verbose log of actions though.